# How do I input from statement in bash script?

Tags: bash, input

I have the following bash script, saved as `script.sh`:

```
echo "Do that? [Y,n]"
read input
if [[ $input == "Y" || $input == "y" ]]; then
        echo "do that"
else
        echo "don't do that"
fi
```

On the terminal, I would like to run the script together with input in a single line. I attempted

```
./trial.sh < y
```

However, I receive the following output

```
bash: y: No such file or directory
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: If you write `<foo`, you are redirecting from a file named `foo`. In your case, a file named `y` would be needed. The file does not exist, and hence the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirection with `<` expects a filename to read standard input from. You could

- use a here-doc:

  ```sh
  ./trial.sh <<'EOF'
  y
  EOF
  ```
- use a here-string:

  ```sh
  ./trial.sh <<< y
  ```
- print a `y` and send it to standard input with a pipe:

  ```sh
  printf 'y' | ./trial.sh
  ```
- or use the `yes` tool, which does exactly that:

  ```sh
  yes | ./trial.sh
  ```

  `yes` can also send other strings: `yes n` prints `n` instead of `y`.

---

Side note: your script can be shortened to

```sh
read -rp "Do that? [Y,n] " input
if [[ $input == [Yy] ]]; then
    echo "do that"
else
    echo "don't do that"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

When you redirect stdin using the `<` the next token on the command line is expected to be  a filename -- thus the error message...

Instead, try "piping" the Input string "y" into your command, like so:

```
echo "y" | ./script.sh
```